# OAuth2 Implemenation with Restsharp portable

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I am trying to authenticate against box.com in my xamarin app. I am using the portable version of Restsharp. [Restsharp Portable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable/)

I am successfully getting the authenticationCode in order to get the AccessToken. I am trying to get the token via:

```
var client = new RestClient(new Uri(baseUrl));
var request = new RestRequest(
                string.Format("/api/oauth2/token"), HttpMethod.Post);

request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
request.AddParameter("code", AppInstance.Instance.boxAuthCode);
request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);

var response = client.Execute<AccessToken>(request);
```

But this code is not working. I am always getting "response: unknown identifier". Do I miss something?